# Performant selection of correct getter based on a string

Tags: java, getter

I have a `list` of strings which relate to particular values to be retrieved (e.g. `volume`, `weight`,...). I receive this list from a query received via an HTTP API endpoint.

Also, there is a class which not only stores `volume` and `weight` but also `size` and `time`. The class has getters for all these fields.

I am looking for a *generic* method to collect a value based on the string in the `list`.

So far, I did:

```java
public double getValue(String fieldName) {
switch(fieldName) {
case "volume":
    return getVolume();
case "weight":
    return getWeight();
case "size":
    return getSize();
case "time":
    return getTime();
default:
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("error");
}
```

Is there a better way to dynamically return a value given a string? Performance is crucial because this generic method is invoked at high frequencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the values in a Map:

```
    Map<String, Double> fieldValues = new HashMap<>();
    fieldValues.put("volume", getVolume());
    fieldValues.put("weight", getWeight());
    fieldValues.put("size", getSize());
    fieldValues.put("time", getTime());
```

and then retrieve them by id:

```
public double getValue(String fieldName) {
    return fieldValues.get(fieldName);
}
```

**If values change** a better approach as Jon suggested is to use a supplier:

```
Map<String, Supplier<Double>> fieldValues = new HashMap<>();
fieldValues.put("volume", () -> getVolume());
fieldValues.put("weight", () -> getWeight());
fieldValues.put("size", () -> getSize());
fieldValues.put("time", () -> getTime());

public double getValue(String fieldName) {

    if (!fieldValues.containsKey(fieldName)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("error");
    }

    return fieldValues.get(fieldName).get();
}
```

Comment: Note that that will only work if the volume, weight etc don't change between the map creation and the time of the call to `getValue`.

Comment: Yes, map values should be updated in that case.

Comment: I think it's at least worth clarifying that then. Alternatively, you could make your map a `Map<String, Supplier<Double>>` and populate it with method references - I suspect that would be a cleaner approach.

Comment: You are right, I just added a clarification

Comment: Your code won't work if there is no value for some specific key

Comment: As Jon already said, if the values of the fields are ever going to change, this code won't work. Providing a `Supplier` instead will fix this: `fieldValues.put("volume", () -> getVolume())`, and then you could call this with `fieldValues.get(fieldName).get()`. Of course, this assumes that the key exists.

Comment: That sounds like it would improve my original code. I'll do some performance testing to evaluate performance as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> *I am looking for a generic method to collect a value based on the string in the `list`.*

It appears that the method `double getValue(String name)` should be extracted in some interface and the classes should implement this interface accordingly:

```java
interface ValueFinder {
    double getValue(String name);
}

class Foo implements ValueFinder {
    private double volume, weight;
    // getters

    @Override
    public double getValue(String name) {
        if ("volume".equals(name)) { // or equalsIgnoreCase is possible
            return volume;
        } else if ("weight".equals(name)) {
            return weight;
        }
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("Field name not found: " + name);
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    private double size, time;
    // getters

    @Override
    public double getValue(String name) {
        if ("size".equals(name)) {
            return size;
        } else if ("time".equals(name)) {
            return time;
        }
        return super.getValue(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, indeed I should think about including some abstractions as well.